# failed to start error while executing apache archiva

Tags: archiva

I have installed apache archiva stand alone in my system.But when i try to start it,itshows the error apache archiva failed to start.My codes are given below

```
D:\apache-archiva-1.3.5>java -version
java version "1.6.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-b33)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode, sharing)

D:\apache-archiva-1.3.5>PATH=c:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk
1.6.0_10\bin

D:\apache-archiva-1.3.5>PATH=c:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk
1.6.0_10\bin;D:\apache-archiva-1.3.5\bin

D:\apache-archiva-1.3.5>archiva.bat install
wrapper  | Apache Archiva installed.

D:\apache-archiva-1.3.5>archiva.bat start
wrapper  | Starting the Apache Archiva service...
wrapper  | The Apache Archiva service was launched, but failed to start.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: prolblem solved.i used archiva console instead of archiva start

Comment: if you have some feedback on the documentation about this (http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3.5/adminguide/standalone.html), please let us know at dev@archiva.apache.org or via the issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 
    C:\apache-archiva-2.2.1\bin>archiva start

if you use console it will work.

```
C:\apache-archiva-2.2.1\bin>archiva console
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:49.022:WARN:oejd.ContextDeployer:ContextDeployer is deprecated. Use ContextProvider
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:49.022:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:49.147:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:49.178:INFO:oejs.NCSARequestLog:Opened C:\apache-archiva-2.2.1\logs\request-20160604.log
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:49.225:INFO:oejd.ContextDeployer:Deploy C:\apache-archiva-2.2.1\contexts\archiva.xml -> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},C:\apache-archiva-2.2.1/apps/archiva
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:53.149:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:53.453:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:11:54.755:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
jvm 1    | Jun 05, 2016 1:12:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
jvm 1    | WARNING: maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 20
jvm 1    | 2016-06-05 01:12:25.275:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```